# Access 2010 - reference form loaded by tab form

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a tab form called Home and I would like to say for example refresh another form loaded in one of the tabs (or the current one).

I tried the following: `[Forms]![Home].[Form]![AnotherForm].[Form].Refresh`

But no joy - what is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Forms![Home]![Name_of_subform_control_on_Home_form].Requery
```

or (alternative syntax):

```
Forms("Home")("Name_of_subform_control_on_Home_form").Requery
```

Some clarification:

1. In Access, nested subforms are always placed in a subform control.
   If you want to access the subform programmatically, you have to use the name of the **subform control**, not the name of the nested subform itself!
2. It doesn't matter whether the subform control is directly on the `Home` form, or in a tab control. You always use the names of the form and of the subform control, you don't need the name of the tab control.

The solution is even shorter when the code that does the refresh is directly in the `Home` form:

```
Me.Name_of_subform_control_on_Home_form.Requery
```

---

**EDIT:**

I just noticed that I used `Requery` instead of `Refresh` in my answer (probably because I read [ChrisPadgham's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9186128/6884) before where he suggests using `Requery`).

You can call both `Requery` and `Refresh` using the syntax shown above.
Which one to use depends on what you want to do:

- Use `Requery` if you want to re-load the data source of the form
- Use `Refresh` if you want to re-load the form itself, i.e. refresh the controls

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response - where do i find the name of the subform control? I take it that is different from the form name itself?!

Comment: @Perplexed, take a look at this: http://www.btabdevelopment.com/ts/ewtrhtrts (especially the first screenshot)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried Requery rather than Refresh